# Are link object can be exported in .obj format

Tags: export

I have link an object from file -> Link and i want that file to be exported to obj to import in sketchup. The original file is much bigger around 220 MB so i link and its in 330 KB and i want to export to obj. Will it export the file for me its not working i tried it. Some time its hang or some time Blender close and im on desktop. There is plugin for sketchup to blender. Is there any addon for blender to sketchup. Or can anybody plz make my link file and export to Obj. Any suggestion or help Thanks.

[image]

Comment: one question per post, please... I guess that those linked objects should be converted to real ones before, as imho the link would now work outsite blender. 220 MB is quite a big file, anyway, and it also could cause export plugins to slow down due to the amount of conversion to do, and perhaps hang. For plugins/addons, you could try if something is lited here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: @m.ardito I have not link with Alt+D to make it real ones. I have link from file menu Link -> group.

Comment: ? I think you should edit your question text and explain better what you did (of course nobody will ask you to share your file to check...). If you used file > link then you linked to another file's group I guess. Since it works with simple objects (I tried), the huge size of your file may be the cause of what you report, but knowing nothing about your file doesn't help to understand. You could try to split your huge file in smaller ones, then export those separately.

Comment: @m.ardito i have attach my link file.

Comment: what should I do with your file...? why don't you just export to obj the original file?

Comment: @m.ardito the problem is that i made the quarter of the model and i cant mirror to other side due to heavy size of the file so i link the 4 side to make my file light and when time to export its hang or cant export.